# How to install vdo/kvdo on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, deduplication

I would like to know if there is a way to install [Red Hat's vdo](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/vdo-quick-start) in Ubuntu 20.04.

So far, I have tried to download the [source](https://github.com/dm-vdo/vdo) and compile it, but I get the following error:

```
cc -fPIC -fpic -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wcast-align -Werror -Wextra -Winit-self -Wlogical-op -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wunused -Wwrite-strings    -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-qual -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wold-style-definition -Wswitch-default   -I. -I../uds -Wno-write-strings -DCURRENT_VERSION="\"8.1.0.316\""   -c -MMD -MF .deps/vdoformat.d.new -MP -MT vdoformat.o -o vdoformat.o vdoformat.c
vdoformat.c:22:10: fatal error: blkid/blkid.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include <blkid/blkid.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I don't get why I get the error because I have the **libblkid** package already installed.

---

What really buggers me is that there is a manpage for [lvmvdo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/lvmvdo.7.html) (what I guess is the "port" to Ubuntu from Red Hat VDO) but it only says:

> For usage of VDO with lvm(8) standard VDO userspace tools vdoformat(8)
> and currently non-standard kernel VDO module "kvdo" needs to be
> installed on the system.

I have indeed the lvm package installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't find the way to install **vdoformat** nor **kvdo** packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of tries and error... I found the way to actually use [vdo](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/storage_administration_guide/vdo-quick-start) in Ubuntu (at least in 20.04)...

First, a quick update and then install some necessary packages:

```bsh
apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && \
apt install git build-essential libdevmapper-dev libz-dev uuid-dev flex bison linux-source libblkid-dev -y
```

Now, just to make sure, upgrade your kernel (default is 5.4) to 5.9 and then restart:

```bsh
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_all.deb && \
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb && \
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb && \
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-modules-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i *.deb && \
shutdown now -r
```

You will now need the [kvdo](https://github.com/rhawalsh/kvdo/tree/master) wich is the kernel utilities to be able to use vdo, next command clone the repo and then compile it:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/rhawalsh/kvdo.git && \
cd kvdo && \
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic/ M=$('pwd') modules
```

Then update our **Module.symvers**, and copy the kvdo module to the respective folder:

```bsh
cat Module.symvers >> /lib/modules/5.9.0-050900-generic/build/Module.symvers && \
mkdir /lib/modules/5.9.0-050900-generic/extra/ && \
cp /opt/kvdo/uds/uds.ko /lib/modules/5.9.0-050900-generic/extra/ && \
cp /opt/kvdo/vdo/kvdo.ko /lib/modules/5.9.0-050900-generic/extra/
```

Now we ask the kernel to update all modules, and then check if it is installed (if **modprobe kvdo** doesnt show anything, then is correctly installed):

```
depmod -a && \
modprobe kvdo
```

You can test the installed version of the kvdo:

```bsh
modinfo kvdo

modinfo kvdo
filename:       /lib/modules/5.9.0-050900-generic/extra/kvdo.ko
version:        8.1.0.316
license:        GPL
author:         Red Hat, Inc.
description:    device-mapper target for transparent deduplication
srcversion:     F021DCCB4284C7E05BCCF77
depends:        uds
retpoline:      Y
name:           kvdo
vermagic:       5.9.0-050900-generic SMP mod_unload
```

The kernel tools are installed, now we need the user-space tools ([vdo](https://github.com/rhawalsh/vdo)), next command clone the vdo repo and compile it:

```bsh
git clone https://github.com/rhawalsh/vdo.git && \
cd vdo && \
make && \
make install
```

You can test if it is correctly installed:

```bsh
vdoformat --version
```

And now you can use vdo as if you are in CentOS....

Answer (score 4):

> I don't get why I get the error because I have the libblkid package already installed.

You need the `libblkid-dev` package which contains the `blkid/blkid.h` header file.

> What really buggers me is that there is a manpage for lvmvdo (what I guess is the "port" to Ubuntu from RedHat VDO) but it only says:

No, this isn't a port of VDO, this is integration of VDO into [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) which allows you to create LVM Logical Volumes with deduplication an/or compression enabled. This is not reimplementation of VDO, LVM uses the existing VDO code -- the `vdoformat` userspace tool and the `kvdo` kernel module, so you still need to install both to make the LVM implementation work.

> I have indeed the lvm package installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04, but I can't find the way to install vdoformat nor kvdo packages.

VDO is not available in Ubuntu ([wishlist bug for 20.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1869825)) so you need to compile it yourself (which you already started) but you need to compile and manually install both the [dm-vdo/vdo](https://github.com/dm-vdo/vdo) project which contains the userspace tools (including `vdoformat` used by LVM) and the [dm-vdo/kvdo](https://github.com/dm-vdo/kvdo) project which contains the kernel module (that's the `kvdo` "package" referred in the lvmvdo man page).